# Git command to get full reference name of current checkout, including tags

Tags: git, build-automation

I am looking for a pure git command that would give the following output:

- If in the branch "somebranch":

  > `[refs/]heads/somebranch`
- if in the tag "1.2.3":

  > `[refs/]tags/1.2.3`

The requirement of being "pure git" is because I need it to be cross-platform.

The "refs" part in path is optional, but the "heads" or "tags" is necessary to me.

I tried different variations of `git describe`, `git name-rev`, `git show-ref`, `git symbolic-ref`, but none of them worked for both branches and tags.

The closest I got is `git symbolic-ref HEAD`, but it doesn't work for tags, since when checked out they are in "detached head" state.

Full context: this is intended to be run in build automation environment so that I can contitionally format the names of the generated build and release artifacts. Conceptually, I want to set the flags "isMaster" (that is, master branch is checked out) and "isTag" (that is, a given tag is checked out).

Answer (score 1):

If your checkout is of a tag, the information may not be available.  If the information is available at all, it is in the *reflog* for `HEAD`.  The only definitely-saved information is the commit hash ID.

If your checkout is of a branch name, `git symbolic-ref HEAD` will produce the correct answer.

If you need the information in a reliable manner, have the CI system save it for you, because Git doesn't.